# material ui withStyles and WithTheme - How to access theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const MySlider = withStyles({
 root: {
    color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main
 }
}, {withTheme: true})(Slider);
```

I did expect the `withTheme` option would make the theme accessible inside `withStyles`. If so then how? because `theme` is not defined and its also not found in `props` ?

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

`withStyles` function can accept a callback instead of an object giving you the access to the `theme` object like this

```js
const NewButton = withStyles((theme) => {
    root: {
        color: theme.palette.primary
    }
}, { withTheme: true })(Button);
```